# How to handle conflicting keybindings

Tags: emacs, keyboard-shortcuts, elisp

[paredit](http://mumble.net/~campbell/emacs/paredit.el) binds `M-<up>` and `M-<down>`, but I want [windmove](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/WindMove) to own those keybindings.  I have paredit-mode set to activate in certain modes only, but windmove is set to run globally.  I want windmove to win, but paredit steals those keybindings when it loads.

How can I easily stop paredit from stomping on windmove's keybindings?  I have been going into `paredit.el` and commenting out the lines which set the keybinding, but this is far from ideal (I have to remember to do this every time I update paredit).

More generally, can I load an elisp file while "protecting" certain keybindings from being changed?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use `eval-after-load` to configure paredit's behavior after loading it, as described in its comments:

```
;;; Customize paredit using `eval-after-load':
;;;
;;;   (eval-after-load 'paredit
;;;     '(progn ...redefine keys, &c....))
```

So, for example:

```
(eval-after-load 'paredit
  '(progn
     (define-key paredit-mode-map (kbd "<M-up>") nil)
     (define-key paredit-mode-map (kbd "<M-down>") nil)))
```

Comment: This is a also great general purpose answer - thanks so much. My one contribution is to point out that if also you want to alter a keybinding (rather than remove it), you would put the name of the paredit function where Emerick put the `nil` above, like I've done for "forward-slurp": `(eval-after-load 'paredit
  '(progn
     (define-key paredit-mode-map (kbd "<M-right>") 'paredit-forward-slurp-sexp)))`

Answer (score 1):

This question has been answered before: [Globally override key binding in Emacs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/683425/globally-override-key-binding-in-emacs)

You create your own minor mode with your preferred keybindings and enable it globally, so that it overrides all other keybindings.