# Tabbar and Orgmode

Tags: emacs

how to overwrite keybinding in orgmode, that tabbar still works with [C-Tab] and [C-S-iso-lefttab]

I tried it this way: 
`(add-hook 'org-mode-hook (lambda ()
                           (global-set-key [C-S-iso-lefttab] 'tabbar-backward)
                           (global-set-key [C-tab] 'tabbar-forward)
))`

My Emacs version is 23.1 and I am using org-mode shipped with Emacs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try the following

`(define-key org-mode-map (kbd "C-<tab>") 'tabbar-forward)`

`(define-key org-mode-map (kbd "C-S-<tab>") 'tabbar-backward)`

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of following org-mode tutorial rules, if you have the following in your .emacs:

```
(require 'org-install)
```

The above will not work. You can brute force your way out of it and add

```
(require 'org)
```

But a more elegant solution would be to embed your (define-key ...) in

```
(eval-after-load "org"
  '(progn
     (define-key org-mode-map (kbd "C-<tab>") 'tabbar-forward)))
```

Answer (score 0):

For the general solution, see [Globally override key binding in Emacs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/683425/globally-override-key-binding-in-emacs)

You create your own minor mode with your preferred keybindings and enable it globally, so that it overrides all other keybindings.