# How to set a keybinding which is valid in all modes in Emacs

Tags: emacs

I've configured my emacs to use `M-j` as `backward-char` by

```
(global-set-key (kbd "M-j") 'backward-char) ; was indent-new-comment-line
```

in my .emacs file. This works fine in many modes (text/org/lisp).

But in `c++-mode` & `php-mode` it is bound to the default `c-indent-new-comment-line`
How can I bind `M-j` to use `backward-char` in these modes too.
And in general for ALL modes.

Thanks,
AnotherEmacsLearner

Comment: Look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/683425/globally-override-key-binding-in-emacs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue was addressed [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/683425/globally-override-key-binding-in-emacs/1758639#1758639). The way to do this is to create a minor mode with your bindings. Your minor mode bindings will shadow any major mode's bindings.

I like your example, since just within the last couple of weeks, I rebound M-h,j,k,l to their equivalent vim movements, and made a minor mode to do it (It turned out to be a great idea. Emacs's default bindings really are terrible). Here's a sample of some of my code:

```
(defvar kirkland-minor-mode-map (make-keymap) "kirkland-minor-mode keymap.")
(define-key kirkland-minor-mode-map (kbd "M-h") 'backward-char)
(define-key kirkland-minor-mode-map (kbd "M-l") 'forward-char)
(define-key kirkland-minor-mode-map (kbd "M-j") 'next-line)
(define-key kirkland-minor-mode-map (kbd "M-k") 'previous-line)
(define-minor-mode kirkland-minor-mode
  "A minor mode so that my key settings aren't shadowed by other major/minor modes"
  t " kirkland" 'kirkland-minor-mode-map)
```

One other thing I should mention is that while this will override any major mode bindings, it can still be overridden by other minor modes which are loaded later.

Comment: feels nice to have my 'own' mode :)

Answer (score 10):

There are policies about which keys are supposed to be mode-dependent and which not. You can overrule bindings changed by a specific mode, but it is a hassle and has to be done for every mode you will be using. It is smarter to keep your own cross-cutting neato bindings to keys that major modes will not touch out of principle. I particularly like the <kbd>F1</kbd>-<kbd>F12</kbd> keys for that, or the Sun Function keys when I can get them. The <kbd>C-c</kbd> + letter sequences are also explicitly reserved for user-defined commands and will not be rebound by major modes. (See: [Key Binding Conventions](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/elisp/html_node/Key-Binding-Conventions.html))

Comment: Oh well; it turns out its not as easy as I thought it would be.

Answer (score 4):

I unset keys that are in the way for specific modes like this:

```
(add-hook 'gnus-summary-mode-hook
          (function (lambda ()
                      (local-unset-key '[M-down])
                      (local-unset-key '[M-up]))))

(add-hook 'org-mode-hook
          (function (lambda ()
                      (local-unset-key '[S-down])
                      (local-unset-key '[S-left])
                      (local-unset-key '[S-right])
                      (local-unset-key '[S-up]))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Nothing can stop any mode from redefining any key any way it wants and it always shadows the `global-set-key`.  So you have to redefine it for every mode that redefines it:

```
(defun redefine-cc-mode-keys ()
  (define-key c-mode-base-map "M-J" 'backward-char))
(add-hook 'c-initialization-hook 'redefine-cc-mode-keys)
```

or similar.