# How do I force a binding in Emacs?

Tags: emacs

I am trying to bind `<C-return>`. I tried `global-set-key` but it didn't work. I then found a suggestion in "[Globally override key binding in Emacs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/683425/globally-override-key-binding-in-emacs)" where someone created a custom minor-mode which included their keybindings, like this:

```
(define-key my-keys-minor-mode-map (kbd "<C-return>") 'insert-and-indent-line-above)
```

Bit it still won't replace the current binding. If I do a `describe-key` and press `C-Return` it tells me that it is bound to `cua-set-rectangle-mark`.

How do I make this binding supersede all other bindings?

Comment: Did you actually try making the minor mode?  It's a clean technique for this sort of thing; if you paste your code then we can help you debug that instead.

Comment: I did. And it is running (I can see `my-keys` next to `ErgoEmacs` :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It sounds like you have [`cua-mode`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CuaMode) enabled, which is setting that binding.  You can disable `cua-mode`:

```
(cua-mode -1)
```

Or, change the binding for `cua-set-rectangle-mark` like so:

```
(setq cua-rectangle-mark-key (kbd "C-S-<return>"))
(cua-mode 1)
```

And then your binding should take effect (using the `global-set-key`).

Comment: I do want cua-mode but changing the key before cua-mode starts did the trick

Comment: +1 for good answer, but a little comment for people trying to use the code as shown here.  It should be (setq cua-rectangle-mark-key (kbd "C-S-<return>")).  Please note the < and > symbols.  It causes an error and it might not be obvious why.

Comment: @Cthutu Thanks for noticing that.  I did it in Emacs, and it actually put the <> around the entire key chord - so I updated with that.

Comment: What's the difference between wrapping the entire chord and just wrapping the return?  Is there a difference?

Comment: @Cthutu That would make a great SO question.  :)  Apparently there is no difference.  I actually prefer the way you have it set up, so I'm editing again.  For more information on accepted syntax, check the documentation for `edmacro-mode` (which apparently isn't documented in *info*.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `global-unset-key`.

```
(global-unset-key (read-kbd-macro "C-<return>"))
```

Comment: if I `eval-region` this line it still doesn't unbind it. very strange.

Comment: Because the binding is in the `cua-mode-map`, not the `(current-global-map)`.  From the docs: "Note that if KEY has a local binding in the current buffer,                                                            
that local binding will continue to shadow any global binding                                                          
that you make with this function."