# How do I rebind ctrl ret in Emacs?

Tags: emacs

I can't seem to rebind ctrl-ret in Emacs. I searched Google extensively, but in the few cases where there was some example of how to rebind it, that example didn't work.
I want to unset the current binding, and replace it with a new one. How do I do this?

Comment: What example?  Surely the exact thing you tried is relevant to your question!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I searched Google extensively, but in the few cases where there was some example of how to rebind it, that example didn't work.

What did you try that didn't work? This works for me in Emacs 24 on Windows 7:

```
(global-set-key [(control return)] 'foobar)
```

**Update**: cua-mode uses `define-key`, try this instead:

```
(define-key cua-global-keymap cua-rectangle-mark-key 'foobar)
```

Comment: Exactly this. ctrl-ret is still bound to cua-set-rectangle-mark.

Comment: OK, think this is a special case, see my update. Also see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3750332/how-do-i-force-a-binding-in-emacs

Comment: I didn't get a chance to try your suggestion since I found the post you linked to about a minute ago, but I'll accept for linking to the post

Comment: Well worth reading: http://www.masteringemacs.org/articles/2011/02/08/mastering-key-bindings-emacs/