# Override Ctrl-TAB in EMACS org.mode

Tags: emacs, keyboard-shortcuts, org-mode

I would like to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> in EMACS for my own use, but Emacs org mode already has this bound. How can I use my own binding instead of the org-mode binding.

In my **.emacs** file I use:

```el
(global-set-key (kbd "<C-tab>") 'switch-view )
```

and it works everywhere except in org-mode

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The key binding you describe is defined in `org.el` like this:

```el
(org-defkey org-mode-map [(control tab)] 'org-force-cycle-archived)
```

This means that it is only valid in `org-mode-map`, one of org-mode's local keymaps.  The following code adds a *hook* that is run when org-mode starts.  It simply removes that key binding from `org-mode-map`.

```el
(add-hook 'org-mode-hook
          '(lambda ()
             (define-key org-mode-map [(control tab)] nil)))
```

Add this code to your .emacs file and then restart emacs.

Comment: Where do I add this "add-hook" line? If I could add it to .emacs it would be ideal :)

Comment: I added this hook to my .emacs file and no change also

Comment: I also tried commenting out the ord-defkey in org.el, but no change. I guess there is some sort of precompiling going on so the modified org.el file is ignored

Comment: @Zubair: Yes, you can just add this to your .emacs file.  I tried it with Emacs 23.2 with the built-in version of org-mode.  You shouldn't need to edit the org-mode sources, but yeah, org.el is ignored if org.elc (compiled Elisp) is in the same directory.

Comment: You can try out the define-key without the hook.  Just start up Emacs, make sure org-mode is loaded (e.g. open an org-file) and paste the following into the *scratch* buffer (without quotes): "(define-key org-mode-map [(control tab)] nil)".  Now move the cursor behind the last parenthesis and press C-x C-e.  This evaluates the last expression.  Try if this has some effect.  If it does the it's the hook that's not working.

Comment: When I enter into the scratch buffer and run "(define-key org-mode-map [(control tab)] nil)" then when I ctrl-TAB from the org-mode I get an error "Arg out of range..."

Comment: So assuming it is the hook that is not working, how can I enable "hooks"? Or do I misunderstand how it works

Comment: Don't bother fixing the hook if evaling define-key doesn't bring the desired effect.  As unsetting a key shouldn't have any dramatic effect though I assume that the "arg out of range ..." error is thrown by switch-view.  Check the meaning of your key binding in the org-mode buffer by hitting 'C-h k' and then 'C-TAB'.

Comment: It says: <C-tab> runs the command org-force-cycle-archived, which is an
interactive compiled Lisp function in `org.el'.

It is bound to <C-tab>.

(org-force-cycle-archived)

Cycle subtree even if it is archived.

Comment: Thanks !!!! "(define-key org-mode-map [(control tab)] nil)" works now. Yes, the out of range error was in my code... thanks for working me through it! :)

Comment: Using eval-after-load will also work (the code needs to be evaluated only once, not everytime org mode is started).

Answer (score 5):

A more robust way to set the keybindings that you want to take effect *everywhere* regardless of the major mode is to define a global minor mode with a custom keymap.

> Minor modes can also have local keymaps; whenever a minor mode is in effect, the definitions in its keymap override both the major mode's local keymap and the global keymap

( http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Local-Keymaps.html )

That way you don't need to mess with the major mode's local keymap every time you encounter a mode that clobbers your keybinding.

See this Q&A for details:
[Globally override key binding in Emacs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/683425/globally-override-key-binding-in-emacs/1758639)

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't work because, as you said, org-mode uses its own keybinding for C-TAB. In other words, even if you define a global keybinding, as soon as you invoke org-mode, it will overwrite that binding with its local keybindings.

What you can do, however, is add a callback function that is invoked whenever you start org-mode, and in that callback function you reset C-TAB to invoke switch-view:

```el
(add-hook 'org-mode-hook (lambda () (local-set-key [(control tab)] 'switch-view)))
```

Put the above line in your .emacs file and next time you start a new Emacs you should be good to go.

Comment: I added the line above to the end of my .emacs file but it had no affect at all

Comment: Did you restart Emacs after adding the line to your .emacs file? Which version of Emacs do you use?

Comment: Actually, I think I like paprika's version better. I've tried that one, too, and it works for me in GNU Emacs 23.1.1.

Comment: Yes, I did restart Emacs, several times. GNU Version 23.2 in "-nw" mode

Comment: Should there be a quote in front of (lambda ... ?

Comment: @JohnD.Cook You could put a quote, but lambda expressions are self-quoting.