# How can I disable the mouse in Emacs term modes?

Tags: emacs, elisp

I would like to disable the use of the mouse within Emacs's term mode. By this I mean that I want mouse clicks within the Emacs terminal window to have no effect; I want mouse clicks elsewhere to be unaffected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use my [disable-mouse](https://github.com/purcell/disable-mouse) package to do this easily, either locally in a particular mode such as `term-mode`, or globally throughout Emacs.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4906534/disable-mouse-clicks-in-emacs) which asks for disabling mouse globally. Here is a modified version to disable mouse only for `term-mode`

```
(eval-after-load "term"
  '(dolist (k '([mouse-1] [down-mouse-1] [drag-mouse-1] [double-mouse-1] [triple-mouse-1]  
           [mouse-2] [down-mouse-2] [drag-mouse-2] [double-mouse-2] [triple-mouse-2]
           [mouse-3] [down-mouse-3] [drag-mouse-3] [double-mouse-3] [triple-mouse-3]
           [mouse-4] [down-mouse-4] [drag-mouse-4] [double-mouse-4] [triple-mouse-4]
           [mouse-5] [down-mouse-5] [drag-mouse-5] [double-mouse-5] [triple-mouse-5]))
    (define-key term-raw-map k (lambda () 
                 (interactive) 
                 ;; ignore this
                 ))))
```

Do keep in mind that by disabling `[mouse-1]` you will not be able to select the terminal with mouse click, so you may want to avoid binding it.

**EDIT**: Wrapped the code in `eval-after-load`