# Is there anyway to disable mouse prompt?

Tags: emacs

I disabled mouse scrolling with `(mouse-wheel-mode -1)`, but when I drag mouse or click mouse, there will warnings like "triple-mouse-4 is undefined", "mouse-3 is undefined" etc.

Is there anyway to disable these prompt as it's very annoying.

FYI, I'm using Emacs 24.3 with X11 in OS X Mavericks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define them as `'ignore`.

```lisp
(dolist (k mwheel-installed-bindings)
  (global-set-key k 'ignore))
```

If you want to disable only mouse scrolling, the following code is better than `(mouse-wheel-mode -1)`

```
(substitute-key-definition 'mwheel-scroll 'ignore global-map)
```

If you want to disable mouse key bindings, see the code at
[Disable mouse clicks in Emacs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4906534/disable-mouse-clicks-in-emacs)
(but `(global-set-key k 'ignore)` instead of `(global-unset-key k)`)

The following advice also solves the problem. It disables all messages shown by `undefined`.
Here I use the macro `noflet` provided by the package `noflet`.
Please install `noflet` by `package-install`.
Since `noflet` is very powerful, I think the solution above is more safe.

```lisp
(require 'noflet)
(defadvice undefined (around no-message activate)
  (noflet ((message (msg &rest args)))
    ad-do-it))
```

Comment: With `(mouse-wheel-mode -1)`, the mouse key bindings have been already unset.

Comment: `mouse-wheel-mode` uses `global-unset-key`.
If a key is unset by `global-unset-key`, then pressing the key shows a message in the echo area.
But binding the key to `ignore`, then no messages are shown when pressing the key.