# Define key-bindings in emacs

Tags: emacs, keyboard-shortcuts

I'd like to map a command in emacs to a key-binding. I want the command `Control-l` to have the same effect as the command `Alt-x goto-line` followed by a return (since that command first needs a return to be invoked and then a line number).

I modified the init file as follows:

`(define-key (M-x goto-line) '\C-l)`

but that didn't work. The error was that `define-key` was being given more than 1 arguments.

Does anyone know how to reset key-bindings in emacs?

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

<kbd>M-g g</kbd> is the default shortcut for `goto-line`. You might want to try that.

To redefine <kbd>C-l</kbd> use:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-l") 'goto-line)
```

Comment: @HemalPandya default for goto-line is `M-g g` or `M-g M-g` as of M-g is a prefix command. you might have rebound it somewhere in .emacs.

Comment: @kindahero you are right. Didn't think `goto-line` will have different bindings in XEmacs and Emacs. I was wrong.

Answer (score 6):

Easiest way to customize lots of keybindings is to install John Wiegley's bind-key module, which is a part of [use-package](https://github.com/jwiegley/use-package) Lisp package. Solution in your [`init.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/InitFile):

```
(require 'bind-key)
(bind-key "C-l" 'goto-line)
```

Minor modes keys usually override global keys, so if you don't want such behavior, use function `bind-key*` instead. The package is on MELPA, if you don't know what is it, quickly learn about [Emacs package management](http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/emacs_package_system.html) (should take you 2 minutes to set up MELPA as your repository).

The main problem with keybindings in Emacs is that minor modes keys often override your custom ones. In vanilla Emacs people workaround by [creating a minor mode for your own keybindings](https://stackoverflow.com/q/683425/596361). If you really wanna understand how Emacs keys work, read [Key Bindings @ Emacs Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Key-Bindings.html#Key-Bindings) and [Keymaps @ Elisp Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Keymaps.html#Keymaps) carefully.

Answer (score 3):

I have set as `(global-set-key (kbd "C-x g") 'goto-line)`. You can use that or `(global-set-key (kbd "C-l")  'goto-line)`.  I would personally do not touch the C-l key from its default behavior.

If you must use M-x define-key, use 
`(define-key global-map (kbd "C-l") 'goto-line).` The 1st argument to define-key is a KEYMAP.