# emacs mode-specific custom key bindings: local-set-key vs define-key

Tags: emacs, elisp

After a few years customizing my `.emacs` file, I find I used two different
kinds of constructs to setup major-mode-specific key bindings:

**1.** using a hook and `local-set-key`. For example:

```lisp
(defun my/bindkey-recompile ()
  "Bind <F5> to `recompile'."
  (local-set-key (kbd "<f5>") 'recompile))
(add-hook 'c-mode-common-hook 'my/bindkey-recompile)
```

I would say this construct makes it easy to use the same key bindings for
different major-modes by adding the same function to all relevant major-mode
hooks (in other words, the "*which keybindings do I want*" is clearly separated
from the "*for which modes do I want them*"). However, I'm not comfortable with
the fact that such customizations are done at the buffer level, whereas I would
think they belong to the major mode.

**2.** using `define-key` (often combined with `eval-after-load` to delay
  evaluation until the relevant keymap is loaded). For example:

```lisp
(eval-after-load "cc-mode"
  '(progn
     (define-key c-mode-map   (kbd "C-c o") 'ff-find-other-file)
     (define-key c++-mode-map (kbd "C-c o") 'ff-find-other-file)))
```

By contrast, this construct customizes the major-mode itself, but is less
flexible: if I want to use the same key bindings for another mode, I will have
to find the correct file and keymap names for this mode, and almost duplicate
the `eval-after-load` expression (although this could probably be automated with
a function/macro).

**Question:** although both construct types work well and produce the result I
want, they are technically very different, setting-up the key bindings in
different keymaps at different times. So my question is: among these two
constructs, is there a "preferred/better" way to do things? (Or maybe the "best"
construct is a third one which I'm not aware of?)

By "preferred/better", I mean such things as:

1. less prone to break with new emacs versions
2. less prone to disturb/be disturbed by active minor-modes
3. more idiomatic / readable / shareable with others

Comment: I discovered the same thing many years later, when I tried to make a major mode that coped with the minibuffer window, that has its own key table and where was compulsory the `local--`.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I believe the two approaches you describe are less different than you think.

Notice that `local-set-key` does in fact evaluate `(define-key map key command)` where `map` is the value of `(current-local-map)`, which is typically set by the major mode.

So although they *could* be doing different things; most of the time the only real difference will be that the hook function with the `local-set-key` call will be setting that same key repeatedly/redundantly, whereas the other approach sets it only once.

You can demonstrate this to yourself by using `local-set-key` in a mode hook, removing that hook function after it has been used, and then creating a new buffer in that same major mode, and testing the binding.

> less prone to break with new emacs versions

I guess you could argue that the name of a keymap might change in future and therefore not needing to know the name is an advantage, but you could equally say the name of the mode hook might change. I don't think either is enough of a concern to worry about.

One thing to note is that `local-set-key` will work even if the major mode did not establish a `current-local-map`, which I guess makes it slightly more robust as far as generalised approaches go.

> less prone to disturb/be disturbed by active minor-modes

There's no difference. All minor mode keymaps take precedence over all major mode keymaps, and neither approach is going to have any effect on the order of `minor-mode-map-alist` (which determines the precedence of minor mode keymaps).

> more idiomatic / readable / shareable with others

They're both entirely readable to my mind, so I can't distinguish them in this aspect either.

I say just use whichever approach seems best to you in each context. I do think it's good to have a standard approach for most things for the sake of consistency in your code, but I doubt it matters which one you choose. There's obviously a saving of a few CPU cycles to be had by not evaluating the same code unnecessarily, but that should matter so very little as to be of no concern whatsoever.

I think the most obvious case for one over the other is the one you already mentioned -- if you want to apply the same binding to multiple modes using a common hook (but not to *all* modes -- for that I thoroughly recommend [creating a custom minor mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/683425)), then a `local-set-key` within that hook is definitely the way to go.

Comment: +1 for the mention that the current local keymap is actually the major-mode-map. Now that I re-read the documentation of `current-local-map` it's pretty clear, but for some reason I had always thought that the local keymap was specific to a buffer and did not impact other buffers using the same major-mode.

Answer (score 2):

I have lots of custom keyboard commands and I couldn't bother with various ways to set them in Emacs and all these keymaps overriding each other, so I just installed John Wiegley's [`bind-key`](https://github.com/jwiegley/use-package) as per [my relevant answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27441765/596361).

```
(require 'bind-key)
(bind-key "C-l" 'goto-line)
```