# Is Emacs supposed to have a hook.el file?

Tags: emacs, elisp

So I've got this file called `hooks.el` in my `emacs.d` with this kind of content:

```
(add-hook 'term-mode-hook ...)
(add-hook 'term-exec-mode-hook ...)
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook ...)
(add-hook 'ido-setup-hook ...)
(add-hook 'makefile-mode-hook ...)
(add-hook 'c-mode-common-hook ...)
(add-hook 'c-mode-hook ...)
(add-hook 'c++-mode-hook ...)
(add-hook 'dired-mode-hook
      (lambda()
        (define-key dired-mode-map "h" 'dired-previous-line)
        (define-key dired-mode-map "j" 'ido-find-file)
            ;; ...
            ))
```

I was just wondering if I'm doing something weird here
or is this indeed the idiomatic way to assign shortcuts based on mode?

I mean here adding hooks instead of plainly writing:

```
(define-key dired-mode-map "h" 'dired-previous-line)
```

Of course, this won't work unless `dired` is loaded and `dired-mode-map` is defined,
hence the hook. And it's probably not the best thing to just load all the modes,
even if I'm not using them always, just to define the custom shortcuts.
But on the other hand, the hook is being run for every new buffer open -
and all these shortcuts are being redefined over and over, instead of just once.

What's your take one the matter? I'm sure there's something more optimal that I could switch to.

In the meantime, I can show off the bookmarklet for my `hooks.el`:

```
(defun goto-hook-file ()
  "Opens hooks.el at point specific to current `major-mode'"
  (interactive)
  (let ((str-mode-hook (format "%s-hook" major-mode)))
    (find-file (concat emacs.d "hooks.el"))
    (goto-char (point-min))
    (search-forward str-mode-hook nil t)))
```

Comment: You should probably change the question title; at the moment it's pretty meaningless. Here's a very similar (if not quite duplicate) Q&A: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9818307/emacs-mode-specific-custom-key-bindings-local-set-key-vs-define-key.

Comment: Wouldn't say that it's entirely duplicate. I couldn't find it before I posted. And now my question has a link to the real deal:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `eval-after-load`:

```
(eval-after-load 'dired
  '(progn
     (define-key dired-mode-map "h" 'dired-previous-line)
     (define-key dired-mode-map "j" 'ido-find-file)))
```

That way, the keys are only defined once.