# emacs get rid of C-x

Tags: emacs

Is there a way I can stop needing C-X before any shortcut and, for example, just use C-c to leave?

Also, if possible, what disadvantages could this have?

I'm looking for a simpler way of using GNU Emacs, but not sure if I can find one.

Comment: You can remap the key combinations however you want, but simple math tells you there will be things that you can't bind to a single key.

Comment: Don't worry, after a while `C-x` shortcuts will become second nature. *Jake: How often does the train go by? Elwood: So often that you won't even notice it.*

Comment: Type ``C-x C-h``. Can you really bind them all to keys?

Comment: `C-c` is probably the last key you should rebind to do something else, because it is reserved as the prefix for major and minor modes. See `(info "(elisp) Key Binding Conventions")`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*(this is too long for a comment)*

Not really an answer but I know that some people hate the *"C-x anything"* in Emacs not just because you have to "type a lot of keys" but also because from a touch-typing point of view *C-x* doesn't make that much sense.

But of course in Emacs everything is configurable.  I'm using *"C-,"* instead of C-x and I honestly find it much easier this way.

I use my left pinky to hit CTRL, which is the key physically located at the left of 'a' on a QWERTY keyboard: *i.e.* the key that used to be CTRL but that now often is labelled CAPS-Lock [and you can remap it to CTRL].

I then touch-type ',' with my right hand.

To this end I added this to my config:

```
(define-key global-map [(control ,)] ctl-x-map)
```

You won't have less keys to type to do, say, a *C-x C-c* (which you can now do both by doing *C-x C-c* or by doing *C-, C-c*), but at least you won't be distorting your fingers as much ; )

Also note that as explained here (see user *"scottfrazer"*'s +40+ upvoted and accepted answer) it may be better to create a minor mode for all your key mappings instead of directly define a global mapping:

[Globally override key binding in Emacs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/683425/globally-override-key-binding-in-emacs)

Comment: Took me several hours to realize that there is no apostrophe before "ctl-x-map"…
But thanks anyway! :)

Answer (score 1):

After looking at the source code of boon.el, I found out about ctl-x-map. C-x is a prefix key, prefix keys often have their own maps.
To use M-m for C-x shortcuts and unbind C-x, use this

```lisp
(global-set-key (kbd "M-m") 'ctl-x-map)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x") nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is a very bad idea, because the C-x prefix can handle such situations like C-x s vs C-x C-s. And: you are really f*cked when you read emacs tutorials and have your own keybindings
If you want some other keybindings read [ErgoEmacs Keybinding](http://xahlee.info/emacs/emacs/ergonomic_emacs_keybinding.html) or [How to Set Emacs's User Interface to Modern Conventions](http://xahlee.info/emacs/emacs/emacs_make_modern.html)

Comment: Yes, good idea, everytime i pressed s boom. I will read those guides, though. Thanks!

Comment: But be forewarned, Xah Lee is a known troll in the usenet, albeit his emacs articles are a good read.

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation is to first learn the standard Emacs key bindings, then, after a while change whichever ones you think will do you the most good to change.

See also CUA mode, in the Emacs docs -- I don't use or recommend CUA mode, but a lot of people (esp. newbies?) use it to keep their cut, copy, paste key habits.