# Disabling adjacent meta keys in Emacs

Tags: emacs, ergonomics

I'd like to change some of my Emacs keyboard habits, as some of the keyboard shortcut combinations (typically starting with C-x, M-x, etc) I do one-handed and they involve uncomfortable hand movements.  I'd like to change this behavior.

However, as I've been doing them for about 15 years, they're programmed into my muscle memory.  It's difficult for me to remember to change the way I type.

I was wondering if it is possible to do a fine-grained remapping in Emacs, even if it's one key at a time, so that (left-control)+x is disabled, but (right-control)+x is still fine, and the like.

Comment: *(not an answer to your question, hence the comment)*... "ctl-x" all done with the left hand is probably the most RSI inducing shortcut ever, due to how often it has to be called.  But you can remap *ctl-x-map* to something else.  Here's what I do to have a saner *ctl-x* in Emacs: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8575726/emacs-get-rid-of-c-x/8581477

Answer (score 1):

You can change "ctrl-x" "meta-x" to other ergo key combo. For example:

1. Caps Lock. You can remap the favorite "meta-x" to this single key. It is super fast and comfortable to type. For windows, autohotkey or keytweak can do the remap job. For Linux, you just change the key layout setting.
2. Ctrl+/. If you have a hhkb keyboard, or you have changed "Caps Lock" to "CTRL". Ctrl+/ is a nice way to replace "Ctrl+x" or "Meta-x". Ctrl+/ is a minor key combo in emacs, so you can change the origin one. it is far easier to type than "Ctrl+x".
3. "Alt"  is better than "Ctrl" because you can type it with thumbs. 
   ergoemacs has some nice keymap tricks. It use "Alt" as main function key. You can find it in https://code.google.com/p/ergoemacs/
   I use this key binding happily and never consider other key-tweak plans again.
4. Buy a better keyboard. Some keyboards change the layout making it easier to type "Ctrl x" "Meta x".
   Kinesis keyboard is a ultimate solution. You may find more alternative with google.
5. Colemak Maltron Dvorak. All of them have a different key layout. If you like to try a new layout. Do'nt forget them. It may help you to handle with "Ctrl x" problem.