# how to define a key to toggle viper-mode in Emacs

Tags: emacs

In Emacs, I want to define the key  to enable/disable the viper-mode. When I press the F6, if viper-mode not enabled, then enable it; if viper-mode enabled, then disable it.
Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

```
(global-set-key [f6] 'toggle-viper-mode)
```

May pose problems in modes which locally rebind <kbd>F6</kbd>. If that happens, see [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/683425/globally-override-key-binding-in-emacs)