# How to disable C-j in emacs major mode

Tags: emacs

I use C-j for 'backward-char; however, when editing a .asm file it overwrites C-j to insert new line.

How do I disable this, and/or rebind to 'backward-char.

Comment: You might want to try: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/683425/globally-override-key-binding-in-emacs

Answer (score 3):

This should do the trick for you:

```
(eval-after-load "asm-mode"
    '(define-key asm-mode-map (kbd "C-j") 'backward-delete-char))
```

(put that in your .emacs).

Answer (score 0):

Try a mode-specific hook:

```
(defun my-asm-mode-hook ()
   (local-set-key (kbd "C-j") 'backward-delete-char))
(add-hook 'asm-mode-hook 'my-asm-mode-hook)
```