# How do I map M-x to "`" key in emacs 24 (Mac OS X Lion)

Tags: macos, emacs, evil-mode

I've downloaded Emacs 24 pretest for Mac OS X and using Prelude + evil kit.
I am coming from vim background and find that M-x is too slow and painful to use. Is there any way to map M-x key to ` key that is near the ESC key? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

```
(global-set-key (kbd "`") 'execute-extended-command)
```

Answer (score 3):

> find that M-x is too slow and painful to use

I'm a touch-typist and I happen to think the same and I also think that, in addition, all the `C-x` shortcuts are very hard to do too.

> Is there any way to map M-x key to ` key that is near the ESC key?

I would say that the ESC key is not really a "close" key: your left pinky has to travel a lot to get there (you either need to move your entire hand, which is not efficient, or you need to "stretch" your fingers).

What I did, on a QWERTY keyboard, is to remap `C-X` to `C-,`

You may want to do something similar: in my opinion it really helps.  So maybe mapping `C-x` to `C-,` and `M-x` to `M-,` would help?

You can do this like the other answer suggested by directly setting a global key:

```
(define-key global-map [(control ,)] ctl-x-map)
```

or you can define your own minor-mode where you put all your mappings and then turn that minor mode on (I learned that here on SO):

```
(define-key my-keys-minor-mode-map (kbd "C-,") ctl-x-map)
(define-key my-keys-minor-mode-map (kbd "M-,") 'execute-extended-command)
... put more mappings here ...

(define-minor-mode my-keys-minor-mode
  "A minor mode so that my key settings override annoying major modes."
  t " my-keys" 'my-keys-minor-mode-map)

(my-keys-minor-mode 1)
```

Or course you "lose" the previous mappings to C-, and M-, but IMHO it's totally worth it.

You probably want to read user *scottfrazer*'s great answer and explanation here (that's what I followed to create my own key minor-mode in my *.emacs* file):

[Globally override key binding in Emacs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/683425/globally-override-key-binding-in-emacs)

Comment: Emacs Version 24.3 (9.0) -- Symbol's value as variable is void: my-keys-minor-mode-map

Comment: @lawlist: yes, it's normal, I just gave an overview here.  In the answer I linked to user *scottfrazer* explains how to *defvar* that minor mode keymap : )   Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you -- I just bookmarked the link and will include a few examples in my Preferences.el -- greatly appreciated.

Comment: @lawlist: the advantage of that method that *scottfrazer* gave is that it's quite clean: you can simply decide not to use that keymap mode and then Emacs is back to the normal/default shortcuts : )   When I read about it I modified my *.emacs* immediately, it's really convenient!