# Stop org-mode from remapping key bindings

Tags: emacs, org-mode, key-bindings

I have a macro I'd like to have at `C+'`, and org-mode remaps this to `org-cycle-agenda-files` for any `.org` buffer, any idea to to prevent this?

Comment: For a more comprehensive solution to precedence issues with custom keybindings, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/683425/globally-override-key-binding-in-emacs/5340797

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I used to have :

```lisp
  (defun org-mode-is-intrusive ()
    ;; Make something work in org-mode:
    ;; (local-unset-key (kbd "something I use"))
    (local-unset-key (kbd "C-'"))
    )
  (add-hook 'org-mode-hook 'org-mode-is-intrusive)
```

in my `.emacs` to deal with such annoyances.