# Hook overwrites user-defined emacs keybinding

Tags: emacs, hook

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Globally override key binding in Emacs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/683425/globally-override-key-binding-in-emacs)

In my `.emacs` file, I added a keybinding for control-meta-h

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-M-h") 'windmove-left)
```

It works fine, as long I don't enter c-mode or c++-mode. Both overwrite it by the default behavior, which is `c-mark-function`. How you I avoid that my binding is overwritten by the c-mode/c++-mode hook?

Comment: Yes, scottfrazer answer in the other question solved my problem. We should close it as a duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can be solved by defining the keybinds in a separate minor mode. For details, see [Globally override key binding in Emacs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/683425/globally-override-key-binding-in-emacs), where scottfrazer provides the following solution:

```
(defvar my-keys-minor-mode-map (make-keymap) "my-keys-minor-mode keymap.")
(define-key my-keys-minor-mode-map (kbd "C-M-h") 'windmove-left)

(define-minor-mode my-keys-minor-mode
  "A minor mode so that my key settings override annoying major modes."
   t " my-keys" 'my-keys-minor-mode-map)

(my-keys-minor-mode 1)
```