# adding a hook to minibuffer-setup-hook breaks key-bindings

Tags: emacs, hook, elisp, key-bindings

i have a few keys that i prefer to force-bind to keys i'm familiar with, and so i have used this [SO Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/683575/774691) .

but i have found recently that it breaks for me.

the circumstances:  it works fine when running 24.2.1 in window mode as build 2012-08-27 on bob.parkland.org (i.e. the pre-build emacs-for-mac solution found at http://emacsformacosx.com/).

but then it will not work when run in terminal on lion, which is 22.1.1 (mac-apple-darwin) of 2012-01-12 on b1006.apple.com .

if i comment out the call to add the hook, it works fine.

Comment: This isn't a comment about this question, but I'm not sure how to get in touch with you otherwise--you left a comment on a question of mine that had a bounty, and your comment turned out to be the answer.  Can you repost it as an answer so I can give you the bounty?  If this is an inappropriate place to make this request, I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is partly that i byte-compiled the code found at the other link above into a separate loadable .elc file … and did so with the newer version of emacs.

when i go back to the 22.1.1 version of emacs and byte-compile it with that version, it works in both versions of emacs without problems.