# How can I disable Esc+<KEY> sending Meta+<Key>?

Tags: iterm2

When I'm in `Emacs` with `iTerm2`, pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd> and <kbd>b</kbd> after in a short time sends <kbd>Meta+b</kbd> which runs `backward-word`. How can I make them separate keys?

I want to make the change in `iterm2` - **independent** of `Emacs`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like the following:

```lisp
(global-set-key (kbd "<escape> b") 'your-function)
```

Hewever, please note that by doing this, you lose the ability to replace the <kbd>M-</kbd> modifier by the <kbd>ESC</kbd> prefix for all other key bindings, not just <kbd>M-b</kbd>.

To limit this potentially unwanted side-effect, you could use the technique presented in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/683575/1225607), to be able to easily switch between your custom behaviour and the standard one.

**Nb:** When using Emacs in no-window mode, please note that this will only work if your terminal sends different inputs for <kbd>ESC</kbd><kbd>b</kbd> and <kbd>M-b</kbd>. Otherwise, there is no way Emacs can tell the difference.

You can check this typing <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>k</kbd><kbd>ESC</kbd><kbd>b</kbd>. If Emacs is receiving a specific input, you will see something like:

> M-b *(translated from <escape> b)* runs ...

Comment: Thanks! Actually I wanted to disable Esc prefix in my terminal, not only in Emacs. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: There might be iterm2-specific solutions to your problem, but I can't help you with this, since I'm no Mac user. I've taken the liberty to retag your question with `iterm2` in case specialists could help you. You might also have more success in asking the question on SuperUser (after rephrasing it on a more terminal-oriented way).