# Binding RET to newline in Emacs

Tags: emacs, key-bindings, ess

In Emacs, while the major mode ESS[S] (Emacs speaks statistics) is in effect, <kbd>RET</kbd> is automatically bound to `newline-and-ident` but I would prefer it to be bound to just `newline`. Following the advice [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/683425/globally-override-key-binding-in-emacs), I bound <kbd>RET</kbd> to `newline`. This works for editing while in ESS, but it has the undesired effect of also affecting commands in the mini-buffer. I cannot use <kbd>RET</kbd> to finish commands in the mini-buffer; instead, it just inserts a new line into the mini-buffer rather than executing the command.

Is there a way to bind the key in a minor mode, but also have it not affect the mini-buffer whatsoever?

Even turning the minor-mode off doesn't seem to work and it would be cumbersome to constantly switch the minor mode on and off even if it did.

This is the relevant part of my .emacs file:

```
(defvar my-keys-minor-mode-map (make-keymap) "my-keys-minor-mode keymap.")

(define-key my-keys-minor-mode-map (kbd "RET") 'newline)

(define-minor-mode my-keys-minor-mode
  "A minor mode so that my key settings override annoying major modes."
  t " my-keys" 'my-keys-minor-mode-map)

(my-keys-minor-mode 1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the answer in your question:

```
(define-key ess-mode-map (kbd "RET") 'newline)
```