# How do I rebind a key in Emacs globally?

Tags: emacs, keyboard-shortcuts, backspace, incremental-search

I have this in my .emacsrc

```
(define-key global-map "\C-h" 'backward-delete-char) ;;previously help
```

however, when I do an I-search and hit `C-h` to delete a char, emacs uses the default binding and tries to open the help, when I cancel the search with `C-g`, it then executes the backward-delete-char in the document I started the I-search from.

EDIT: This makes me wonder why `C-h` is again mapped to `help` inside the minibuffer. What is overriding my global-map definition and why?

Answer (score 2):

You can use this:

```
(keyboard-translate ?\C-h ?\C-?)
```

This will translate C-h to backspace everywhere.

When you do `isearch` or `ido-find-file`, they
override some keys in the minibuffer. You could re-override
these keys for each mode, but you'd have to really do it for each
new mode that you use. That's why I've suggested the code above:
modes will not typically rebind backspace to something that doesn't behave
like a backspace. The point is that the logical <kbd>C-h</kbd> is still
bound for help inside minibuffer, but with `keyboard-translate` you don't
have <kbd>C-h</kbd> anymore - you just have another backspace. And if you
want to bind some command to it, you can't bind to <kbd>C-h</kbd> -
you have to bind to `?\C-?`.

Comment: This seems like a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/683425/globally-override-key-binding-in-emacs?rq=1 but it's interesting that your suggestion hasn't been mentioned over there. I'd like to know why, are there problems with your method?

Comment: I haven't experienced any problems. It effectively just remaps the keys on your keyboard. But if you bind something to backspace, the same thing will be bound to `C-h`: they're now the same key.

Comment: I like your answer, but I want to get a better understanding of the issue first. I edited my question accordingly. Maybe you know why minibuffer mode overwrites my global remapping?

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you don't really want to delete a char when you hit "control and h", but instead that for some reason Emacs receives `C-h` when you press the backspace key, right?

If so, the best solution is to figure out how to change your terminal emulator so that it doesn't send `C-h` to Emacs when you press backspace (e.g. it could send `C-?` as do most other terminal emulators nowadays).

Comment: Nope, I want to delete a char in when i hit `C-i` when editing text. I modified my question to make this more clear.