# Emacs - Key Rebinding Not Working

Tags: emacs, elisp, loading, key-bindings

I want to use Undo Tree Mode, and I have the undo/redo key bindings set up successfully.

However, when I try to overwrite the default <kbd>C-/</kbd> binding with a commenting function I wrote, the combination is still bound to undo-tree-undo.

Here is what I tried:

```
(eval-after-load 'my-functions
  '(eval-after-load 'undo-tree
    '(define-key global-map (kbd "C-/") 'my-commenting-function)))
```

I have it load after my-functions so my-commenting-function can be called.

After trying this, with Undo Tree Mode enabled, <kbd>C-/</kbd> is still bound to undo-tree-undo and not my-commenting-function.

How can I change the Undo Tree Mode key binding for <kbd>C-/</kbd> to the function I want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do this to define a global binding:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-/") 'my-commenting-function)
```

Do this to stop a minor mode from overriding it:

```
(define-key undo-tree-map (kbd "C-/") nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

As @abo-abo has alluded to the problem is the order in which key-bindings are evaluated. If you read the Emacs documentation (http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Active-Keymaps.html#Active-Keymaps) you will see the keymaps are searched in order:

```
keymap, minor mode maps, local keymap, global keymap
```

There are two approaches to avoiding the sort of aliasing you describe. Either modify any minor mode keymaps that clash or set the buffer keymap directly (say with a hook function). Also there is a convention that C-c 'letter' is reserved for user mappings and in theory shouldn't be overridden by any other modes so you could consider using one of those bindings instead.

Comment: there's another approach which consist in creating your own minor mode keymap for all your keymappings. I'm using the one explained by user *scottfrazer* here (71+ upvotes as I type this) and it's working fine (and seems to work fine to override the C-/ *undo-tree-map* OP mentioned in his question) : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/683425/globally-override-key-binding-in-emacs