# redefined keys doesn't work correctly

Tags: plugins, emacs, key

I've redefined key bindings for some basic movement functions in my `init.el` file:

```
(global-set-key "\C-j" 'backward-char)
(global-set-key "\C-k" 'next-line)
(global-set-key "\C-l" 'forward-char)
(keyboard-translate ?\C-i ?\H-i)
(global-set-key [?\H-i] 'previous-line)

(global-set-key "\M-j" 'backward-word)
(global-set-key "\M-l" 'forward-word)
```

And in general (text editing) it perfectly works, but in some modes it executes multiple commands, e.g. in `Buffer` mode when I press <kbd>C-k</kbd> aside from moving the cursor down Emacs marks the listed buffer for deletion. Also, when I call `helm-prelude` with <kbd>C-c p h</kbd> and press one of these key bindings Emacs either doesn't react at all or, in case of <kbd>C-k</kbd>, clears the search bar. I thought that the purpose of `global-set-key` was to bind commands to specific keys everywhere, am I wrong?

Comment: Probably a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/683425/globally-override-key-binding-in-emacs

Answer (score 1):

**Local** (e.g., major-mode) keymap bindings trump **global** keymap (`global-map`) bindings. And **minor-mode** keymap bindings trump both of these.

There is a *hierarchy* of several keymap types that determines which maps take precedence. See the Elisp manual, node `Controlling Active Maps` (and nearby nodes about keymaps).  The full hierarchy is a bit complicated, but most of the time what you need to be aware of is what I stated in the preceding paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the global keymap is only used when there is no binding for the key being pressed in a local keymap.  For example, the buffer menu mode uses `Buffer-menu-mode-map`, where `C-k` is bound to `Buffer-menu-delete`.

You may have better luck using `keyboard-translate` to translate these keys to the "normal" Emacs bindings for those commands, i.e. `C-p`, `C-n` etc.