# How to unbind "M-1" and "M-2" in Emacs ansi-term

Tags: emacs

I use tabbar in emacs, and bind following key.

```
(global-set-key (kbd "M-2") 'tabbar-forward-tab)
(global-set-key (kbd "M-1") 'tabbar-backward-tab)
```

But, those key-binds don't work in ansi-term mode. When I type 'M-1', it do not run tabbar-backward-tab, the key is captured by bash.

```
[xx@local ~]$ 
(arg: 1)
```

How to unbind "M-1" and "M-2" in Emacs ansi-term?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Globally override key binding in Emacs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/683425/globally-override-key-binding-in-emacs)

Comment: When I see people wanting to rebind `M-<n>` (or `C-<n>`) it always makes me think that they're missing the usefulness of numeric prefix arguments, and the convenience of those default bindings.

Comment: @phils You are right, I miss usefulness of numberic prefix arguments, but bind "M-1" on tabbar-backward-tab is more convenient for me. BTW, can we distiguish key ALT and ESC in emacs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `term-char-mode` <kbd>M-<n></kbd> sequences are bound to `term-send-raw` (as are most sequences which a terminal would normally handle).

To unbind them, you can use:

```el
(eval-after-load "term"
  '(progn
     (define-key term-raw-map (kbd "M-1") nil)
     (define-key term-raw-map (kbd "M-2") nil)))
```

That will stop them from shadowing the global bindings.