# Emacs Key Binding Precedence

Tags: emacs, autocomplete, elisp, code-snippets, evil-mode

I'm frustrated with the default behavior of `autocomplete` overriding key bindings used by `yasnippets`.

Is there a way to set a precedence so that tab will try to expand a snippet before trying to autocomplete the word?

Quick disclosure: I'm using evil-mode.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If they're both minor modes, then precedence is determined by the order of elements in `minor-mode-map-alist` which, unless explicitly manipulated, is simply determined by the order in which the libraries were loaded.

Ensure that `autocomplete` is loaded *before* `yasnippet`, and yasnippet's minor mode map would have precedence.

You could also use `eval-after-load` to adjust `minor-mode-map-alist` after loading `autocomplete`, to check for a yasnippet entry, and re-order the list if necessary.

(`autocomplete` may use other methods, though. A temporary overriding keymap would still have precedence over the minor mode maps, for instance.)

Comment: Could you provide an example of how to re-order the list? I tried to delete yasnippet's and then append back (hopefully at the end of the list) yasnippet with eval-after-load with autocomplete, but my delete operation with the following code: (setq minor-mode-alist (delete '(yasnippet keymap) minor-mode-alist)) but the keymap for yasnippet was not deleted.

Comment: (1) `minor-mode-map-alist`, not `minor-mode-alist`. (2) See an example at https://stackoverflow.com/a/5340797