# emacs: Define the priority of key event processing among minor modes (org-cdlatex-mode and company-mode)?

Tags: emacs, autocomplete, completion

In my Emacs (spacemacs) setup, with `org-mode`, I like to use both `company-mode` and `org-cdlatex-mode`.

I like `company-mode` to provide autocompletion most of the time, but I'd like to have cdlatex's auto-completion triggered by `TAB` first, only if cdlatex's autocompletion finds no completion, then the company's autocompletion should be used.

What would be the best solution?

- I figure that I could somehow arrange the priority in processing the key  event of `TAB`, letting cdlatex have the priority. (But how?)
- Or, write my own `TAB` event dispatcher: first call `org-try-cdlatex-tab`, only if it return false, then call company-mode's function for `TAB` event processing. (This would be very customized, will be complicated to maintain.)
- Or, use a different key for cdlatex autocompletion (This is quite doable, but requires additional human memory.)

Comment: I just tracked the code of org.el, it turned out that "TAB" event triggering the call to org-try-cdlatex-tab is dispatched by org-cycle, therefore, it's a conflict between org-mode and global-company-mode.

Comment: This may be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/24687923 (which discusses the priority of minor mode keymaps) ?

Comment: Yes, it's duplicated.