# How to disable local key binding in octave-mode?

Tags: emacs, octave, key-bindings

Here is my key binding.
I want to set `C-h` to delete-backward-char in all modes, but in octave mode, when I pressed `C-h`, it shows `C-h (Type ? for further options)-`. So I add the last 3 lines in my `.emacs` file, but it doesn't work. `C-h` still works as the help function.

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-?") 'help-command)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-h") 'delete-backward-char)
(define-key octave-mode-map (kbd "C-h") nil)
(define-key octave-mode-map (kbd "C-h a") nil)
(define-key octave-mode-map (kbd "C-h d") nil)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`octave.el` appears to set those bindings in three different keymaps:

- `octave-mode-map`
- `inferior-octave-mode-map`
- `octave-help-mode-map`

You might also refer to [Globally override key binding in Emacs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/683425/globally-override-key-binding-in-emacs)