# Can't rebind C-M-q in emacs

Tags: emacs, key-bindings

I'm trying to set some custom bindings and have ran into a puzzling problem, I'm unable to rebind C-M-q or unbind it entirely. I have no trouble rebinding other keys, so I don't know what is special about C-M-q. Below are some of the things I've tried in my .emacs file.

```
;;(global-set-key (kbd "C-M-q") nil)
;;(global-unset-key (kbd "C-M-q"))
;;(global-set-key (kbd "C-M-q") 'shrink-window-horizontally)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-M-y") 'shrink-window-horizontally)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-M-w") 'shrink-window)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-M-e") 'enlarge-window)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-M-r") 'enlarge-window-horizontally)
```

No matter what I try, the C-h k command says C-M-q is bound to

> C-M-q runs the command indent-pp-sexp, which is an interactive
>   compiled Lisp function in `lisp-mode.el'.
>
> It is bound to C-M-q.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **global** keymap is the lowest-priority keymap, whereas this binding is in the **local** (major mode) keymap for the buffer you are looking at (which is a lisp buffer), so Emacs never sees your global keymap changes, because it has found a binding before getting that far.

Specifically, this binding is in `lisp-mode-shared-map` (a parent keymap for several lisp modes), which is shadowing a more generic binding in `prog-mode-map`. Other programming modes have their own bindings for this key, to ensure that it will always have some kind of "indent expression" behaviour.

As such, I would *suggest* you don't clobber this binding, as there's a standard use for it. If you *really* want to do so, then you should look at [Globally override key binding in Emacs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/683425).

Emacs has many layers of keymaps, and it's important to have an idea of how the system works, so I highly recommend taking the time to read the following article on the subject:

https://www.masteringemacs.org/article/mastering-key-bindings-emacs